# How to assign the value of textbox in first form into a checkbox on another form

Tags: vba, checkbox, textbox, variable-assignment, ms-access-2003

Of course this must be simple. I have done this a thousand times but today I cant see the wood for the trees somehow. I want to do this... Me!ProjectID = Forms!Another.ProjectID
But I have the Another field reporting in the watch window correctly as value 50, and after assignment Me!ProjectID = 1....Dur!

I have tried it using periods instead of exclamation marks and using the .value property but nothing is altering the value post assignment to what it should be.
Its in the Form_open procedure. the checkbox, it has a lookup and ProjectID is the bound column.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: It gets weirder. 
        Dim l As Long
        l = Forms!Feature!ProjectID.Value
        Me!ProjectID = l
Braking and inspecting after the last assignment l=0 and Me!ProjectID = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep Braindead day - the answer is simple an OnCurrent event was also firing and resetting the ProjectID value!